# Message Box showing multiple times when progress bar complete in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, progress-bar, msgbox

I am trying some with progress bar, but it's not showing popup correctly. When i use msgbox, its appears 100s of times and when I use form2 by replacing msgbox it keep showing even I close it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
        If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
            MsgBox("Done")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show message only once then stop the timer before the message box

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
      Timer1.Stop()
      MsgBox("Done")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer for the solutions that worked for you. It help others who are facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not `disable` or `Stop` the timer. when the `ProgressBar1.Value` reaches the maximum the message box will display as `"Done"` but timer is still executing so you will get the message till timer is disabled, since the condition `If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then` is true. so you need to disable the timer if the condition is true.

```
If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
  Timer1.Enabled = False
  MsgBox("Done")
End If
```

or you can use   `Timer1.Stop()`